# How to seperate your work into different gits

Tags: git, split

Mij development files are way more than what my production server requires. So I wish to create two git's and be slective. But how would one create a scenario.
And I was wondering I cannot be the only one. If only I could have two different .gitIgnore files. 
The reason for this question is I don't want my Sass, Pug, PSD, etc files going to my production server. Any suggestions?

[I've included an image of what I want to acheave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otg5L.png)

Comment: By "a git" you mean "a git repository"?

Comment: Yes two Git Repo's yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My development files are way more than what my production server requires

If you're after simple deployment, `git archive` will create an archive in which you can selectively ignore and edit files.  Add the `export-ignore` attribute to any file you don't want archived; add the `export-subst` attribute to any file you want Git to replace the `git log` "pretty formats" substitutions between `$Format:` and `$` on (so you could have `README.* export-subst` and commit `README for commit $Format:%h, committed on %cd$`, then the readme's in the archive would say what commit and commit date it's built from.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've never used `git archive`, I'll have to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution to this problem is to use a build/deployment process (and tools) that can assemble the files needed in production (and no others) and put them there.

The use of git for deployment is a shortcut that is workable in simple scenarios (but that I don't recommend ever).  You have a (somewhat) more complex case - what you deploy isn't a complete image of your source work tree - so you should consider whether it's worth the trouble to hang on to this shortcut.

The idea of "two `.gitignore` files" wouldn't help.  A `.gitignore` file does not limit what part of a repo's content is seen at checkout; rather it allows for local files that are not already tracked in the repo to *not* be reported or added by default.

You *could* set up a "sparse checkout" on the server.  If you really want to check out just part of the work tree, then that is the feature you need to look up.  But again, this would just be adding complexity to use a tool for what it's not designed for, rather than adding to your process the tools that are designed for what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So your suggestion is that I look at git pipelines? That sounds complicated no? Any suggestions?

Comment: Discovered Github Actions - Bitbucket CDI is a bit on the heavy side to bite down

Answer (score 0):

So a workaround that I found is webpack. 
In the root folder I've got the developer git
and in the Build (dist) folder I've got the production git.
Just make shore you do not delete the git every time you rebuild